# How to sort an array of floats in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Just wondering how to sort an array of floats in Ruby, since "sort" and "sort!" only work for integer arrays.

Comment: Both methods work fine with floats, or floats mixed with integers. Are you sure there's nothing else wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you should show some code where you're seeing this problem.

Answer (score 7):

Arrays of floats can certainly be sorted:

```
>> [6.2, 5.8, 1.1, 4.9, 13.4].sort
 => [1.1, 4.9, 5.8, 6.2, 13.4]
```

Maybe you have a `nil` in your array, which *can't* be sorted with anything.

Comment: Thank you. I had a NaN hence why I got the: in `sort': comparison of Float with Float failed (ArgumentError)

Answer (score 4):

You can sort a float array without any problem like :

```
irb(main):005:0> b = [2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 4.0]
=> [2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 4.0]
irb(main):006:0> b.sort
=> [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 4):

perhaps you have something like this in your array and haven't noticed:

```
[1.0 , 3.0, 0/0, ...]
```

the `0/0` will give you a `NaN` which is impossible to compare with a Float... in this case you should try to

```
[2.3,nil,1].compact.sort
# => [1,2.3]
```

that or perhaps the same error with `1.0/0` wich yields infinity (but this error is detected by ruby)

Comment: but maybe some more illustration on the subject is advised (took me a while to realize it)

Comment: Glad you posted this answer. This was exactly the problem I had and the other answers didn't illustrate what was going on very well.